# SMBJ: What is the SMBJ api to copy a directory containing files to my local machine

Tags: smbj

Can anyone please let me know what is the SMBJ API to copy folder/files from fileshare to my local machine ?

Also, if possible can i get an example for the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've obtained the File from the `DiskShare`, you can just call `File.getInputStream()`, and copy the bytes to a local `java.io.FileOutputStream` like you would do with a regular file copy in Java.